# Laravel loading relations - framework bug?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have encountered something strange which I consider might be a bug in the framework itself so I'm wondering if there were similar experiences with it.

I have two entities: `Contact` and `Media` in a 1:M relationship. Relationship is defined as:

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Media::class);
}
```

Now the issue I see is that when I go on `show` controller method and load the relation like this:

```
public function show(Contact $contact)
{
    $contact->load('media');
    return response()->json($contact);
}
```

The contact is resolved fine, with media relationship in the following way:

```
"first_name": "Melisa",
...
"media": [
    {
        "id": 50,
    ...
```

However if I modify the case of the relationship so that I call:

```
public function show(Contact $contact)
{
    $contact->load('mEdIa');
    return response()->json($contact);
}
```

It returns:

```
"first_name": "Melisa",
...
"m_ed_ia": [
    {
        "id": 50,
    ...
```

...which is really disturbing. Is it supposed to happen?

Comment: That's the nature of this beast. How could it distinct your intentions if your keys are all the same. `mEdia` becomes `m_edia`, this is not a bug, but a user error.

Comment: Yeah, but from my perspective `mEdia` shouldn't be allowed. My relationship function name is `media`, and I want it to be used as such. For multiple word relations I want also consistent naming. Having for example `statusTypes`...I don't want `sTaTuSTYpE` to be called as a relation if that's not the function name.

Comment: No maybe I wasn't clear enough, or you just don't know. PHP is case insensitive, so how do you expect this behavior to be corrected if it is unable to verify.

Comment: The logic that converts the underscore is case sensitive, otherwise it would not know where to put the underscore. With that in mind, it is not hard to strict compare 2 strings

Comment: I think we started on a wrong path here, I'll answer to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour should be noted in the documentation of Laravel, which is indeed not the case. If I were you, I would open an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework) on updating the documentation about this behaviour, and see what the response will be.

But to come to terms, this is a **feature**, not a *bug*.

The nature of PHP is sensitive and insensitive in many ways. For classes and methods; PHP is insensitive.

```php
class Contact {
    public function media() {
        return .. relationship;
    }
}

// valid
new CONTACT();
(new contact())->mediA();
// valid reflection
$r = \ReflectionClass('contact');
$r->hasMethod('mediA'); // true
```

So this quirky stuff is all valid. Now to the point you said:

> .. from my perspective `mEdia` shouldn't be allowed. My relationship
> function name is `media`, and I want it to be used as such.

Then you have to write it as such. You **have** to because Laravel depends on it.

- PHP is simply unable to validate/verify.
- Laravel has to change the nature of a programming language where its sensitivity is deliberately designed by choice.
- The expectation here is; you (as a programmer) should know about PHP's sensitivity, so in this case, there is absolutely no need to validate the given input.
- The overhead to validate/verify such a thing would be tremendous and would not make sense.

```php
$class = 'contact';
$method = 'mediA';

$r = new \ReflectionClass($class);
if($class !== $r->getName()) {
    throw new \Exception('unknown class');
}
if(!in_array($method, array_map(function($method) {
    return $method->name;
}, $methods))) {
    throw new \Exception('unknown method');
}

// valid from here
```

From all points of view, the usage of `$contacts->with('mediA')` is completely valid.

The fact that `mediA` becomes `medi_a` using `Str::snake('mediA')` when converting to an array (as such), is simply a feature of Laravel you have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

There is such behaviour in Laravel. To get the same key 'mEdIa' - you have to add to `media` model.

`public static $snakeAttributes = false;`

Comment: Yeah, but I want to keep the behavior for a 2 word relationships. If I have `customFields` relation, I want the user to retrieve `custom_fields` property...not `cu_stomfiel_ds` one...